# Everywhere continuous extension of a almost everywhere continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ a Radon measure. If $f$ is continuous outside a set $N$ of $\mu$-measure 0, does there exist an everywhere continuous $g$ such that $f = g$ on $X - N$?

Answer (score 3):

The signum function, i.e $$
  sgn(x) = \begin{cases}
    -1 &\text{if $x < 0$} \\
     0 & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
     1 &\text{if $x > 0$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
is a counter-example to your claim.

Comment: @T.Bongers No it doesn't. That function indeed *can* be made continuous by changing it only on a set of measure 0, namely by changing it on $\{0\}$. (The comment was referring to a claim that the function which is zero everywhere except at $0$ works too)

Comment: Yes, you're quite right; I meant to say $\chi_{[0,1]}$, the indicator function of the unit interval.